# How to make a condition with EF Core 5 using concrete type (aka "The LINQ expression could not be translated" issue)?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, linq-to-sql

I am trying to make a join and then filter the results:

```cs
var result = context.Test1
    .Join(context.Test2, q => q.Test11, q => q.Test21, (q, p) => new Tuple<Test1, Test2>(q, p))
    .Where(q => q.Item1.Test2 == "test")
    .ToList();
```

The above query is throwing an exception:

```
The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Test1>()
.Join(
    inner: DbSet<Test2>(), 
    outerKeySelector: t => t.Test11, 
    innerKeySelector: t0 => t0.Test21, 
    resultSelector: (t, t0) => new TransparentIdentifier<Test1, Test2>(
        Outer = t, 
        Inner = t0
    ))
.Where(ti => new Tuple<Test1, Test2>(
    ti.Outer, 
    ti.Inner
).Item1.Test2 == "test")' could not be translated
```

The problem is here: `new Tuple<Test1, Test2>(ti.Outer, ti.Inner).Item1.Test2 == "test")`. When I use an anonymous type for join it works well:

```cs
var result = context.Test1
    .Join(context.Test2, q => q.Test11, q => q.Test21, (q, p) => new { q, p })
    .Where(q => q.q.Test2 == "test")
    .ToList();
```

But the issue is that I am building the query dynamically (using [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)) and thus I need a concrete type to be able to build the query. So I am using a method like:

```cs
private static Expression<Func<Tuple<Test1, Test2>, bool>> GetTransactionsSearchPredicate(string[] values)
{
    var searchPredicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Tuple<Test1, Test2>>();

    foreach (var val in values)
    {
        searchPredicate = searchPredicate.Or(q => q.Item1.Test2 == val);
    }

    return searchPredicate;
}
```

I also tried to change `Tuple` to a custom type but the error is the same.

Is there anything I could do to make this work? It used to work with EF Core 2 but I think it was just executed locally…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.Tuple` support is constantly changing/breaking between EF Core versions, so its usage is unreliable.

For EFC 5.0.10 (latest official at this time), it does not work, but custom generic type *with settable properties* (instead of immutable type with constructor as `System.Tuple`) does. e.g. if you replace `Tuple` with let say `Pair` having the following signature:

```cs
public class Pair<T1, T2>
{
    public T1 Item1 { get; set; }
    public T2 Item2 { get; set; }
}
```

and of course change the constructor call with the more verbose

```cs
.Join(context.Test2, q => q.Test11, q => q.Test21,
    (q, p) => new Pair<Test1, Test2> { Item1 = q, Item2 = p }) // <--
```

Comment: This is weird because I already tested the custom class but it didn't work. Maybe it wasn't public? Anyway, works like a charm!